# BufferedReader creating odd characters, which character encoding do I use?

Tags: java, character-encoding, bufferedreader

I am trying to take multiple text files and merge them all in to one new file.  However, looking at the new file that was created there are some weird characters that have replaced quotation marks and I can't figure out why or how this is occurring. Tried specifying the encoding but it did not solve the problem.  Am I using the wrong character encoding?

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName), "utf-8");
```

Here is the issue:

Original file contains:

```
|3_PatFemale("X")|3_PatSex (”M” or “F”)|
```

New file contains

```
|3_PatFemale("X")|3_PatSex (�M� or �F�)|
```

code:

```
BufferedWriter out =  new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(exportFile),"UTF-8"));

for (File f : files) {
        FileInputStream fis;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

            String aLine;
            while ((aLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                out.write(aLine);
                out.newLine();
            }

            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to use the encoding with FileOuputStream as well, which you have not shown in your code here.

Comment: sorry I added that small line at the top

Comment: Thanks. Had to change the encoding to ANSI. Which I believe solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Change the contents of the file form this

```
|3_PatFemale("X")|3_PatSex (”M” or “F”)|
```

to

```
|3_PatFemale("X")|3_PatSex ("M" or "F")|
```

The quotation you are using

```
”
```

(prime quotation mark)

is different from

```
"
```

For further reference: https://askleo.com/why_do_i_get_odd_characters_instead_of_quotes_in_my_documents/

Comment: unfortunately this a file format I am receiving so I have no power over changing them :(